# be seen to do/be seen to have done

Tags: infinitives

Usually, a plain infinitive is used with "be seen".

> She was seen to leave at 9.

But is it possible to use the perfect infinitive? Here is one example which seems correct.

**If a player is seen to have played an illegal card, that player must take two additional cards from the stack.**

Can you confirm if it's correct and how it would differ from

**If a player is seen to play an illegal card, that player must take two additional cards from the stack.**

Comment: **A player is seen to play a card** - someone observes them playing it. **A player is seen to have played a card** - the card is visible on the table after they have played it.

Comment: In practice, I don't think there's much difference in meaning. "seen to have played" emphasises that the punishment occurs afterwards, while "seen to play" may refer to something you do at the time you see them, but in writing rules, tense is not very important and either would be OK.

Comment: In other words, to follow up on @KateBunting's comment, with **A player is seen to play a card**, you need to catch them in the act. If this were the rule, then you could distract everyone ("Look over there!") and play an illegal card. Then, even though everyone might later notice that you **have played** an illegal card, they didn't technically see you play it, so you could argue you shouldn't be punished. The perfect infinitive covers the history of the game, not just a moment in time, so it avoids silly disputes about abusing the rules.